# Vectorized pdf cropping

Tags: pdf, images, vector-graphics, crop

I need to crop a few pdf files, to create four pages from each source page. I know, hot to do that with ImageMagick, but it can't work with vector images, which pdf is, so the resulting quality is far from good. Is there any programme, which would let me do this and not lose image (mostly,text, actually) quality?

**EDIT:**
I want this. I have a pdf file, created from a presentation, and each page of it contains 4 slides from a presentation.

I want each of these pages to became a separate page.

Comment: 4 separate pdf files or some other file format? Or are you saying that a page of the presentation in the PDF file contains 4 slides. Essentially the PDF was generated with 4-up. See this URL for examples: of 1-up, 2-up, 4-up, http://formaxprinting.com/blog/2010/05/07/printing-lingo-what-does-up-mean-as-in-2-up-3-up-4-up-multiple-up/. You want to print each of the slides in the 4-up on it's own individual page.

Comment: http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/13/0511/h_1368271165_2917829_622b2b0920.png
You can see it there. It seems, it is printed 4-up, yes.

Comment: Also, I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, but I have found the right programme: briss, http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/

Comment: Yeah we found it at the same time, I just added it to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of tools that can manipulate PDF files:

- [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) "If PDF is electronic paper, then pdftk is an electronic staple-remover, hole-punch, binder, secret-decoder-ring, and X-Ray-glasses. Pdftk is a simple tool for doing everyday things with PDF documents."
- [pdfsam (PDF Split and Merge)](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=42): "pdfsam is an open source tool (GPL license) designed to handle pdf files"
- [PDFJam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam/) "A small collection of shell scripts which provide a simple interface to much of the functionality of the excellent pdfpages PDF file package (by Andreas Matthias) for pdfLaTeX." (You can also use pdfLaTeX directly.)

#### Example

So you want to remove 'page 13' from in1.pdf to create out1.pdf:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-12 14-end output out1.pdf
```

#### Converting 2-Up, 4-Up back to 1-Up

The OP modified the question afterwards and added some additional requirements. They were looking to be able to take a 2-Up or 4-Up PDF file and convert it to a 1-Up PDF file. This tool looks like it can do this.

- [briss](http://briss.sourceforge.net/) - This project aims to offer a simple cross-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac OSX) application for cropping PDF files. A simple user interface lets you define exactly the crop-region by fitting a rectangle on the visually overlaid pages.
  It's licensed under GPL!
- [Printing Lingo: What does “Up” mean…as in 2-Up, 3-Up, Multiple-Up?](http://formaxprinting.com/blog/2010/05/07/printing-lingo-what-does-up-mean-as-in-2-up-3-up-4-up-multiple-up/)

#### References

- [Modifying PDF files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/modifying-pdf-files)

Comment: Thank you! I know there are a lot of such tools, but is any of them capable of what I need?

Comment: They all can do what you want, if I understand your question. I've added an example of how to cut page 13 from a pdf file and write the remaining pages (1-2,14-end) to a new pdf file.

Comment: Ok, it seems, I wasn't clear enough, about what I need. I'll change the question to make it more clear.